# Oracle Data Pump Import TSTZ version

Tags: oracle19c

I'm trying to import a Oralce database dump exported from Oracle 19c and see this below error

```
ORA-39045: Oracle Data Pump does not support importing from a source database with TSTZ version 34 into a target database with TSTZ version 32
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on this

Comment: The destination database needs to be patched with a more current time zone file.  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/update-database-time-zone-file

Comment: How can we get this timezone file without having Oracle corporate account

Comment: I'm not sure you can without a license.

Comment: Without looking at what version of the time zone file ships with each database release, if you're trying to import into something other than the most recent version of the database that you can download from OTN, you could try downloading and installing a more recent version of Oracle and importing into that.

Comment: Yeah, i downloaded the latest from Oracle 19c windows version which is latest 19.3 as per Oracle,

Comment: I suppose the other option would be to try setting up an Oracle Autonomous Database Free Tier account and importing into a 21c database.

Comment: thanks @JustinCave, will try to see this option if it works